# Determine whether timestamp is 50 seconds ago

Tags: php, timestamp

How to know if `$database_row_datetime` is 50 seconds ago?

For example:

```
if $database_row_datetime is 50 seconds ago {
    echo "This post was sent now";
}
```

Here is my timestamp variable:

```
var_dump($database_row_datetime) => string(19) "2015-04-28 15:20:09"
```

Comment: If it is less than one minute ago (eg 50 seconds ago), or if it is more than (eg 2 minutes ago)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if ((time() - strtotime($database_datetime)) < 60) {
```

This is a quick, dirty solution for one if statement.

The correct way to handle this is with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes.

Comment: Assuming $database_datetime is in standard UNIX time format.

Comment: strtotime() will correctly handle almost any format that someone would put in a database, but I was also editing the answer to include something a bit more robust. strtotime() actually does not take a UNIX formatted time as its argument.

Comment: tested and no working;

Comment: @MarleneOliveira could you paste the output of var_dump($database_datetime) for us?

Comment: var_dump: string(19) "2015-04-28 16:38:09"